# Combo Box Boolean in Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, combobox, boolean, contact-form

I'm on visual studio and I have trouble doing some boolean on Visual Basic for a Combo Box Boolean. I am using Visual Studio btw. I tried to add the following:

```
if ClientBox.ValueMember() = "Agentleader1 (Leader)" Then
```

But it wouldn't work.

My program is a basic Contact-Us form for a person to fill out. A field (the combo-box field, called: clientbox) is a combo-box to where you can select which member of the whole group you want to send the contact-form to. Which is a problem. I'm very sorry I can't give a sample of the code. And btw, I just started C++ please don't give complex answers and maybe add a few annotations so I can understand. Please comment this question if I have not explained enough about my program! BTW, please no C# answers.

Comment: This is so wrong on so many levels of basic syntax, that you should really start by reading a book on C++ before trying anything more complicated.

Comment: @nvoigt I'm not a reader type of person!

Comment: If your question is about "Visual Basic" (as it says in the subject and the code), why are you using the "c++" tag? And if you're not a "reader type of person", how do you expect to read the answers here? This is not a "post some nonsense and get an answer" site. If you want help, please put some effort into asking a serious, well-formed question here. Adding random tags that have no meaning is a waste of our time (and yours).

Comment: @KenWhite I can't delete the question :3 if u are a mod of higher of stack overflow, can u please delete for me, I AM SURE I DON'T WANT IT, I'm done asking, please delete the question if you are a mod or higher that can delete questions, thx ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, if anybody is wondering here it is, sorry for my amateur-ness! This actually kinda is a better answer than anything I could have come up with (except the fact that I found this answer by myself:

```
if ComboBox.SelectedItem().Equals("any choice of one of the items") = True Then
    'execute command!
```

The above was the syntax, I got an example of my code below:

```
if ClientBox.SelectedItem().Equals("Agentleader1 (Leader)") = True Then
TEA = "****" 'That's my email!
```

Hope this helped to anybody that couldn't figure out how to find whether a specified item that is selected in a certain combo-box is selected!

Comment: This is not C++. Maybe you should look twice what programming language you are using? Might have yielded better results here, too.

Comment: @nvoigt Well I'm **SORRY**. Again I just started! So I am an honest amateur, maybe you can tell me how to tell what language it will be in!

Comment: @Agentleader1, it doesn't matter if you're a beginner or not, you should at least know if you're using C++ or Visual Basic. They're two totally different languages.

Comment: @Agentleader1: Sorry, but pleading "newb" here doesn't work. "Please answer this question about dogs" and adding tags related to cats and birds is simply ridiculous. If you can't figure out what language you're trying to write code in, you need to stop trying to program until you can understand that first. "I want to speak some words, but I don't know what language I want to use" makes no sense.

Answer (score -2):

is that exactly how it is written in your code? the single '=' is an assignment operator... you need '=='

Comment: Visual Basic uses `=` as both an assignment and an equality operator.

Comment: ah, got ya... i thought this was c++